# Kotlin 'when' statement vs Java 'switch'

Tags: java, switch-statement, kotlin

Pattern matching in Kotlin is nice and the fact it does not execute the next pattern match is good in 90% of use cases.

In Android, when database is updated, we use Java switch property to go on next case if we do not put a break to have code looking like that:

```
switch (oldVersion) {
    case 1: upgradeFromV1();
    case 2: upgradeFromV2(); 
    case 3: upgradeFromV3();
}
```

So if someone has an app with version 1 of the DB and missed the app version with DB v2, he will get all the needed upgrade code executed.

Converted to Kotlin, we get a mess like:

```
when (oldVersion) {
    1 -> {
        upgradeFromV1()
        upgradeFromV2()
        upgradeFromV3()
    }
    2 -> {
        upgradeFromV2()
        upgradeFromV3()
    }
    3 -> {
        upgradeFromV3()
    }
}
```

Here we have only 3 versions, imagine when DB reaches version 19.

Anyway to makes when acting in the same way then switch? I tried to continue without luck.

Comment: Just stumbled on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-771 any workaround then?

Comment: I think statistically (no evidence, but I'm sure Kotlin team used statistics to decide) that a `switch` in Java almost always has a `break` in each case, therefore it is  inconvenient for the common case.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Simple but wordy solution is:

```
if (oldVersion <= 1) upgradeFromV1()
if (oldVersion <= 2) upgradeFromV2()
if (oldVersion <= 3) upgradeFromV3()
```

Another possible solution with [function references](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references):

```
fun upgradeFromV0() {}
fun upgradeFromV1() {}
fun upgradeFromV2() {}
fun upgradeFromV3() {}

val upgrades = arrayOf(::upgradeFromV0, ::upgradeFromV1, ::upgradeFromV2, ::upgradeFromV3)

fun upgradeFrom(oldVersion: Int) {
    for (i in oldVersion..upgrades.lastIndex) {
        upgrades[i]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but you can use recursion instead of calling method from for loop

Comment: @SurajVaishnav why is using recursion better? Using `tailrec` would be fine, but the loop is pretty straightforward, IMO.

Answer (score 18):

edit: Original response below. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
fun upgrade() {
    fun upgradeFromV1() { /* Do stuff */ }
    fun upgradeFromV3() { /* Do stuff */ }

    tailrec fun upgradeFrom(version: Int): Unit = when (version) {
        LATEST_VERSION -> {
            Config.version = version
        } 1 -> {
            upgradeFromV1()
            upgradeFrom(2)
        } in 2..3 -> {
            upgradeFromV3()
            upgradeFrom(4)
        } else -> {
            Log("Uncaught upgrade from $version")
            upgradeFrom(version+1)
    }

    upgradeFrom(Config.version)
}
```

---

Here's a variation on the answer @C.A.B. gave:

```
fun upgrade(oldVersion: Int) {
    when (oldVersion) {
        latestVersion -> return
        1 -> upgradeFromV1()
        2 -> upgradeFromV2()
        3 -> upgradeFromV3()
    }
    upgrade(oldVersion + 1)
}
```

Comment: Add a [tailrec](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#tail-recursive-functions) modifier to the (recursively called) function and you're golden!

Comment: @Jerzyna edited in my current solution, which is slightly nicer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 14):

How about this:

```
fun upgradeFromV3() {/* some code */}
fun upgradeFromV2() {/* some code */ upgradeFromV3()}
fun upgradeFromV1() {/* some code */ upgradeFromV2()}
fun upgradeFromV0() {/* some code */ upgradeFromV1()}

fun upgrade(oldVersion: Int) {
    when (oldVersion) {
        1 -> upgradeFromV1()
        2 -> upgradeFromV2()
        3 -> upgradeFromV3()
    }
}
```

Added:

I like the idea by [@lukle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41238275/4083820) to define the upgrade path as a list. This allows to define different upgrade paths for different initial stage. For example:

1. Simple fast path from released version to the latest released version
2. Catch-up path from hot-fix version (could be few in a row), which should not be applied when going from previous full version to the next full version

For that we need to know from which elements of the list to apply.

```
fun <Vs, V> Pair<Vs, V>.apply(upgrade: () -> Unit): (V) -> V {
    return { current: V ->
        if (first == current) {
            upgrade()
            second
        } else {
            current
        }
    }
}

val upgradePath = listOf(
        (0 to 10).apply  { /* do something */ },
        (5 to 15).apply  { /* do something */ },
        (10 to 20).apply { /* do something */ },
        (15 to 20).apply { /* do something */ },
        (20 to 30).apply { /* do something */ },
        (30 to 40).apply { /* do something */ }
)

fun upgrade(oldVersion: Int) {
    var current = oldVersion
    upgradePath.forEach { current = it(current) }
}
```

In this code Vs could be the same as V or some kind of collection of V values with overridden `equals(other: Any?): Boolean` method.

Answer (score 11):

You can just use for loop with when.

```
for (version in oldVersion..newVersion) when (version) {
    1 -> upgradeFromV1()
    2 -> upgradeFromV2()
    3 -> upgradeFromV3()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about Kotlin DSL for custom implementation? Something like this approach:

```
class SwitchTest {

    @Test
    fun switchTest() {

        switch {
            case(true) {
                println("case 1")
            }
            case(true) {
                println("case 2")
            }
            case(false) {
                println("case 3")
            }
            caseBreak(true) {
                println("case 4")
            }
            case(true) {
                println("case 5")
            }
//          default { //TODO implement
//
//          }
        }
    }
}

class Switch {
    private var wasBroken: Boolean = false

    fun case(condition: Boolean = false, block: () -> Unit) {
        if (wasBroken) return
        if (condition)
            block()
    }

    fun caseBreak(condition: Boolean = false, block: () -> Unit) {
        if (condition) {
            block()
            wasBroken = true
        }
    }
}

fun switch(block: Switch.() -> Unit): Switch {
    val switch = Switch()
    switch.block()
    return switch
}
```

It prints:

`case 1
case 2
case 4`

UPD: Some refactorings and output example.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutly possible 
quote from official reference : [Control Flow: if, when, for, while](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

```
If many cases should be handled in the same way, the branch conditions may be combined with a comma:

when (x) {
    0, 1 -> print("x == 0 or x == 1")
    else -> print("otherwise")
}
```

So if same condition list is short, then you can list them separating by coma, or use ranges like condition in 1..10 as stated in other answers

Comment: How does that help with OP's problem?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Although it doesn't directly answer the question, it does answer a related question of handling various cases in the same way

Answer (score 2):

Another variation of OP's answer:

```
override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    when (oldVersion) {
        newVersion -> return
        1 -> TODO("upgrade from v1 to v2")
        2 -> TODO("upgrade from v2 to v3")
    }
    oldVersion++
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
}
```

Comment: This seams like infinite recursive loop

Comment: @C.A.B. My original answer implied that `oldVersion` would have to be incremented inside the `when` statement. I have edited the answer to explicitly show that `oldVersion` has to be incremented in order to avoid infinite recursion. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Kotlin does not allow you to oldVersion++, because val cannot reassigned. You can instead onUpgrade(db, oldVersion + 1, newVersion)

Comment: @Nishita, yes, thank you for this remark. I will delete this post later on, as it seems to me little different than Julian Delphiki's post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mix of the two answers from bashor, with a little bit of functional sugar:

```
fun upgradeFromV0() {}
fun upgradeFromV1() {}
fun upgradeFromV2() {}
fun upgradeFromV3() {}

val upgrades = arrayOf(::upgradeFromV0, ::upgradeFromV1, ::upgradeFromV2, ::upgradeFromV3)

fun upgradeFrom(oldVersion: Int) {
    upgrades.filterIndexed { index, kFunction0 -> oldVersion <= index }
            .forEach { it() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't care about the order in which you run these functions, you could make your own pseudo-switch, something like:

```
function PretendSwitch() {
  if(oldVersion>3) return
  upgradeFromV3();
  if(oldVersion==3) return
  upgradeFromV2()
  if(oldVersion==2) return
  upgradeFromV1()
  if(oldVersion==1) return
}
```

Nothing is going to be as clean as using a switch. Unfortunately, Kotlin lacks a switch statement so there is no way do perform this elegantly.

Answer (score -1):

```
val orders = arrayListOf(
            { upgradeFromV1()},
            { upgradeFromV2()},
            { upgradeFromV3()}
)

orders.drop(oldVersion).forEach { it() }
```

Answer (score -2):

val oldVersion = 6
val newVersion = 10

```
for (version in oldVersion until newVersion) {
    when (version) {
        1 -> upgradeFromV1()
        2 -> upgradeFromV2()
        3 -> upgradeFromV3()
        4 -> upgradeFromV4()
        5 -> upgradeFromV5()
        6 -> upgradeFromV6()
        7 -> upgradeFromV7()
        8 -> upgradeFromV8()
        9 -> upgradeFromV9()
    }
    println("~~~")
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Kotlin works with a different flow control called when.

Your code, using it when, can be that way.

Obviously the code could be different, but I understand that your question is only about the use of switch.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val month = 8

val monthString = when(month) {
    1 -> "Janeiro"
    2 -> "February"
    3 -> "March"
    4 -> "April"
    5 -> "May"
    6 -> "June"
    7 -> "July"
    8 -> "August"
    9 -> "September"
    12 -> "October"
    11 -> "November"
    10 -> "December"
    else -> "Invalid month"      
}

println(monthString);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.