# Fall through in Kotlin: Switch/When without break

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and I want to do a switch that don't have a 'break'. In java would be like that:

```
    switch (b){
        case 3:
            Log.d("int", "3");
        case 2:
            Log.d("int", "2");
        case 1:
            Log.d("int", "1");
    }
```

And if b = 2 then it would print:

> D/int: 2
>
> D/int: 1

I want to do that in Kotlin without repeting the same code for each case. In a kotlin convertor, the code output was that:

```
when (b) {
  3 -> {
    Log.d("int", "3")
    Log.d("int", "2")
    Log.d("int", "1")
  }
  2 -> {
    Log.d("int", "2")
    Log.d("int", "1")
  }
  1 -> Log.d("int", "1")
}
```

Is there another way of doing that? My actual code is way bigger than that;

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30832215/2027146 Refactor each statement in your `switch` statement into methods and then use `if` instead. It's not as clean as Java IMO. But it will get you there

Comment: @Milk, works great when you are switching on something like an int that increases or decreases in value.  Doesn't work so well when you are switching on a string.