# Android kotlin how to have switch conditions without break statement

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I had `switch` in Java without break statement. when i converted to Kotlin. it has put `When` which i tested and executed only the condition i pass to that function

here is the code of **JAVA**

```
 switch (version) {
            case 1:
                onCreate(db);

            case 2:
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ");
        }
```

**KOTLIN**:

```
 when (version) {
                1 -> {
                    onCreate(db)
                }

                2 -> {
                    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ")
                    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ")
                }
            }
```

Comment: According to https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/fall-through-in-when/2540/2, the "fallthrough" feature doesn't yet exist for kotlin but they want to implement "continue" at some point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["When" statement vs Java "switch" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832215/when-statement-vs-java-switch-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
if (version <= 1) {
    onCreate(db)
}

if (version <= 2) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ")
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ")
}
```

Comment: That's not much of a parallel.

Comment: @shmosel it appears to be the JetBrains recommended way to mimic java-style fallthrough: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/fall-through-in-when/2540/2

Answer (score 0):

You can always customise your when with ranges in kotlin [here](https://antonioleiva.com/when-expression-kotlin/) read more

```
     when {
            version in 0..1  -> {
                onCreate(db)
            }
            version in 1..2 -> {
                //do something else
                onCreate(db)
                dbExe(db)
            }
            else ->{
               //handle unexpected here    
            }
        }

fun onCreate(val db: SQLiteOpenHelper){
  //oncreate goes here
}

fun dbExe(val db: SQLiteOpenHelper){
  // execute sql statement goes here
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ")
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ")
}
```

Comment: NAh. this wont work, coz i dont want same case statement to execute again everytime.