# How can kotlin's 'when' expression make a process as this switch-case code?

Tags: kotlin, switch-statement, kotlin-when

```
int num = 100;
char c = 'a';

c = someBigTask(c);

switch (c) {
case 'a':
    num += 100;

case 'c':
    num += 10;

case 'd':
case 'e':
    num += 100;
}
```

I want to eliminate same code by 'when' expression in another condition like this switch-case code, but I couldn't find the solution..

---

I did like this for this problem:

```
var num = 0
when(c){
            'a' -> num += 100
            'a', 'c' -> num += 10
            'a', 'c', 'd', 'e' -> num += 100
            else -> 0
        }
```

and I getted the result excuted only `'a' -> num += 100`..

Can I get the solution with only 'when' expression in this problem?

Comment: Sadly kotlin `when` does not support fall-through like java switch. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832215/when-statement-vs-java-switch-statement).

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin the equivalent `when` expression is the following:

```
val c = // some char
val num = 100 + when (c) {
    'c' -> 10
    'a', 'd', 'e' -> 100
    else -> 0
}
```

Note that in this case the `else` case is necessary as [`when` **must** be exhaustive](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) as it's used as en expression, i.e. it must cover all possible values of `c`. If `c` were a `Boolean` for example (or an `enum` or any other value with a limited domain), then you could have covered all possible cases without an `else` case, so the compiler would have allowed the following:

```
val c = // some boolean
val num = 100 + when (c) {
    true -> 10
    false -> 0
}
```

`when` doesn't need to be exhaustive if it's not used as an expression but as a traditional control flow statement (like pre-Java 12 `switch` statement), as in the following snippet:

```
val c = // some char
var num = 100

when (c) {
    'a', 'd', 'e' -> num += 100
    'c' -> num += 10
}
```

Comment: Why not `'a', 'd', 'e' -> 100`?

Comment: Thanks for your the fastest answer, but I have some question in that kotlin case.
In the switch-case code, if var c has 'a', then num will have 210 by including the process in case 'c' & case 'd', 'e', but the code in your answer, with a condition c = 'a', can't make that num has 210 by not including the process in case 'c'.
I felt some lack of demonstration, so I added my trying in my question.

Comment: @raklai what you're looking for is called `fallthrough` and it's the default behaviour of Java's `switch` but unfortunately it's not available (yet) in Kotlin as of version 1.3 so you can replace it with a series of `if` statements for instance