# Kotlin "when" without break (option that switch case in java had)

Tags: android, kotlin

When I write:

```
num = 3
switch (num){
        case num < 2:
            Log.d("int", "3");
        case num > 2:
            Log.d("int", "2");
        case num > 0 :
            Log.d("int", "1");
        case num > 40:
            Log.d("int", "10");
    }
```

This will print case 2 and case 3.

I want to do the same in kotlin without using multiple if/else statements in situations like this. When{} doesn't help me since as AFAIK it has a mandatory break when we enter case and it doesn't go further through cases.
Does anyone know nice solution for this?

Comment: perhaps related or a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832215/kotlin-when-statement-vs-java-switch

Comment: Yes it is similar. But this was asked 6 years ago so I expected that maybe some new options arrived to solve this problem

Comment: Unfortunately kotlin's `when` doesn't support what you are looking for. They've had a plan to introduce a `continue` keyword but it's been 3 years now and no update.  Here is the relevant discussion: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/fall-through-in-when/2540

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're asking is allowing `fallthrough` in switch statements. **Kotlin does not support this** with `when`.

Allowing fallthrough can easily cause bugs as it's not explicit enough. Jetbreans team seems to have a "[tentative plan](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/fall-through-in-when/2540/3)" of supporting the `continue` keyword in when statements to allow fallthrough. That would make it explicit.

Some workarounds are suggested in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832215/kotlin-when-statement-vs-java-switch), but using multiple if statements is probably the cleanest way going forward with Kotlin right now.

Here's the discussion in kotlinlang about this: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/fall-through-in-when/2540